# What are CDC/CLDC in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, cdc, cldc

Our current projects are in J2ME, and I'm used to android, trying to understand J2ME is a little confusing, I can't seem to understand the architecture well.

Comment: http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/1401-what-are-cdc-and-cldc.html

Comment: Thanks but I did see that, I was looking for more insights.